# Duplicate object names in MS Unity (App Block)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'll try to make this simple!

For the Unity registration piece:

```
// ====================================================================
// NOTE:  This fails as the WithName.TypeName is Payload for all jobs!  
// HOW can we make the name for payloads "[JobName].Payload"??
// ====================================================================
_container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath()
    .Where(type => (typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(type) || typeof(IJobPayload).IsAssignableFrom(type)) && type.IsClass),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.TypeName,
    WithLifetime.Transient);
```

Where:

```
public interface IJob
{
    bool Execute<T>(T payload) where T : class, IJobPayload;
}
public interface IJobPayload
{
    string JobName { get; set; }
    string JobQueueName { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    JobType JobType { get; set; }
    CronExpression Cron { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can build various jobs.  Something like:

```
public class Job1 : IJob
{
    bool IJob.Execute<T>(T payload)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(Payload))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expecting an object with a type of {typeof(Payload)}!");

        Console.WriteLine("public class Job1 : IJob");
        return false;
    }

    public class Payload : IJobPayload
    {
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public string JobQueueName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public JobType JobType { get; set; }
        public CronExpression Cron { get; set; }
        // --- job specific data -------------------
        public string Job1ExtraData { get; set }
        public datetime Job1Created { get; set }
    }
}

public class Job2 : IJob
{
    bool IJob.Execute<T>(T payload)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(Payload))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expecting an object with a type of {typeof(Payload)}!");

        Console.WriteLine("public class Job2 : IJob");
        return false;
    }

    public class Payload : IJobPayload
    {
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public string JobQueueName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public JobType JobType { get; set; }
        public CronExpression Cron { get; set; }
        // --- job specific data -------------------
        public string Title { get; set }
        public int Count { get; set }
    }
}
```

The problem comes when trying to resolve a concrete class for `Job1.Payload` or `Job2.Payload`.  Both get the same name in Unity:  `Payload`!

As the project I am working on has many, many jobs and we wanted to build a template for creating new jobs (Add > Job), we prefer having the payload model a child of the job.

Right now I have controller code that takes in a JSON representation of a `Payload` object:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(dynamic json)
{
    var container = UnityHelpers.GetConfiguredContainer();
    var jobName = GetJobNameFromJson(json); // JsonConverter will not work until I can resolve *which* payload definition I want, brute force it for now...
    var job = container.Resolve<IJob>(jobName);
    // ====================================================================
    // how do I get it to a point where this will resolve.
    // (see original NOTE at top of question)
    // ====================================================================
    var payload = container.Resolve(typeof(IJobPayload), $"{jobName}.Payload");

    job.Execute(payload);
}
```

How do I work with this in Unity (or any other IoC container)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of the overload of `RegisterTypes` that you are using is of type `Func<Type,string>`. The `RegisterTypes` method will invoke this delegate for each type it finds to obtain a name for the registration.

`WithName.TypeName` is simply a static method that returns the name of the type.

You can create your own method or lambda expression that is smart enough to detect if the type is a nested type. Here is an example:

```
t => t.IsNested ? t.DeclaringType.Name + "." + t.Name : t.Name
```

So your registration statement would look like this:

```
_container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath()
        .Where(type => (typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(type) || typeof(IJobPayload).IsAssignableFrom(type)) && type.IsClass),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    t => t.IsNested ? t.DeclaringType.Name + "." + t.Name : t.Name,
    WithLifetime.Transient);
```

Comment: I was almost there!  Just going down a wrong route.  Thanks much!